# Prove that the two line<->circle intersecting points multiplied by eachother are equal to the square of the circle's tangent

Tags: geometry, circles

On my current math assignment there is a question as follows:

Prove the following:

A line $k$ through point $P$ intersects a circle in the points $A$ and $B$. Another line $l$ also through $P$ is tangent to the circle in point $C$. Then the lengths $PA$, $PB$ and $PC$ satisfy
$$
PA\cdot PB = PC^2
$$

Can anyone give me any clues as to how to prove this?

Comment: I've added details to the question without which it had no chance of being true; please correct if I added the wrong ones.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed this is much better.

Comment: There is no need to worry.This is a very common result and people would easily recognize it when someone says '$PA.PB = PT^2$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested result is actually the consequence of a theorem called "power of a point".

To prove it, (referring to the drawing), Knowledge required are

[image]

1. angle ABC = angle ACP -- [for the reason of "angles in the alternate segment"].
2. $\triangle PCB$ ~ $\triangle PAC$ --[for the reason of "equi-angular"].

Result comes out after setting up the corresponding ratios.

Answer (score 1):

Let the center be 'O' and drop a perpendicular from 'O' to AB and let this point be 'D'.

$(PD – AD) (PD + BD)$

$= (PD – AD) (PD + AD) $

$= PD^2 – AD^2$

In right ΔOPD,

$OP^2 = OD^2 + PD^2$

$⇒ PD^2 = OP^2 – OD^2$

∴ $PA . PB = (OP^2 – OD^2) – AD^2 = OP^2 – (OD^2 + AD^2)$

In right ΔOAD,

$OA^2 = OD^2 + AD^2$

∴ $PA . PB = OP^2 – OA^2 = OP^2 – OT^2 (OA = OT)$

In ΔOPT,

$OP^2 = PT^2 + OT^2$

$⇒ OP^2 – OT^2 = PT^2$

∴$ PA . PB = PT^2$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$PC^2=MP^2-r^2$

$MP^2-r^2 =PA \times AB $ (Why?)

Here's the proof:

$PA=PB-AB$

$AB = 2(r^2 -MX^2)$

$MX^2=MP^2 - (PX^2) \implies MP^2 - PA+ (\dfrac{AB}{2})^2$

Now you can complete the proof yourself.!

Comment: Great answer! But I still have problems deducing MP^2 - r^2 = PA x PB from the last step...